# Can the field type of a foreign key be different to the referenced primary key?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I get a E-R model which is not designed by me. But I have no way to contact the author. 
There are something confusing me in this model. 
In Table A, the Primary Key is an integer field. Table B has a Foreign Key referenced to the PK of A. But this FK of B is a varchar field.
I just start learning the database dedign, and never see or do that in my jobs.
Is it reasonable and realizable?
Note that the model is for mysql.

Comment: A foreign key doesn't have to reference the primary key of the parent table. A foreign key can reference any key in a table. Could it be that the foreign key in B is really referencing a varchar column in A and not the primary key of A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can't be implemented as a FOREIGN KEY constraint in InnoDB; the datatype of the foreign key column(s) must match the datatypes of the referenced column(s) EXACTLY.

You can perform a join operation on the columns, although there's going to need to be datatype conversion on one side or the other... e.g.

```
ON c.character_col + 0 = p.numeric_col
```

It's permissible to do that in SQL; we don't have to have a FOREIGN KEY constraint defined in order to perform join operations.

This design is not one we like to see; one of the big issues is performance, in that MySQL can't make effective use of an index on `character_col`.